# Place dimensions on an object

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I can't find a way to place the dimensions of an object, be it a line, a square or a circle; Any method in Python to place the dimensions of any object like in Auto Cad? , I am working with `tkinter` and `canvas`; Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend checking out the [Question Guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting a useful answer. Update your question with things you have tried, sample code that didn't work, etc. Good luck!

Comment: The canvas has a documented method for creating text. Have you tried using it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question:

To place a tkinter canvas line in a specific dimension, you should do:

```
from tkinter import *
class dimensionPlace:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root)
        self.canvas.create_line(200, 0, 200, 200) # Creates a line from (200, 0) to (200, 200)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()


dimensionPlace()
```

The parameters for create_line is: x1, y1, x2, y2, where x1 and y1 are the x and y coordinates for the starting point, and x2 and y2 are the x and y coordinates for the ending point.

**EDIT**: The formula to find the length of a line is this, assuming that you have variables self.linex1, self.linex2, self.liney1, self.liny2 and you have included the line "from math import *": self.linelength = sqrt((self.linex2 - self.linex1) ** 2 + (self.liney2 - self.liney1) ** 2)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing "out of the box" in `tkinter` to do what you want. You will have to write your own geometry manipulation procedures to position the desired dimensions on your objects.

for instance:

[image]

that is done with something like this:

```
import math
import tkinter as tk


class Line:

    def __init__(self, canvas, start, end, unit='px'):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.unit = unit
        self.draw()

    @property
    def mid_offset(self):
        x0, y0 = self.start
        x1, y1 = self.end
        offset = 20
        return (x0 + x1 + offset) / 2, (y0 + y1 - offset) / 2

    @property
    def angle(self):
        x0, y0 = self.start
        x1, y1 = self.end

        angle = math.atan2(-(y1 - y0), x1 - x0) * 180 / math.pi
        while angle < 0:
            angle += 360
        return angle
        # return 45

    def __abs__(self):
        x0, y0 = self.start
        x1, y1 = self.end
        return round(((x0 - x1) ** 2 + (y0 - y1) ** 2) ** .5, 2)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(*self.start, *self.end)
        txt = f'{abs(self)} {self.unit}'
        self.canvas.create_text(*self.mid_offset, angle=self.angle, text=txt)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
    canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    Line(canvas, (50, 50), (300, 300))
    Line(canvas, (10, 350), (350, 200))

    root.mainloop()
```